# Java Regex that accept any string other than all dashes

Tags: java

I have facing problem for creating a Regex that accept any string other than all dashes i.e. if string contains all the dashes it should be rejected.

i tried `[0-9-]*` but it accept all dashes
and `-*[0-9]+` it does what i want but don't allows shuffling(I mean mixed string of 0-9 and -(dash)).

for example trt-09tr- should be accepted.
---rte434rt should be accepted.
- should be rejected.
------ should be rejected.
---6 accepted.
--u accepted.

if some one could help me.
thank you

Comment: What are 'all dashes'? Which characters do you want to exclude?

Comment: What about 9---- or 7-7-7? Rejected or accepted?

Comment: both are accepted BTW @Marko Topolnik answer is perfect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want negative lookahead for that, one that matches the whole input: `(?!^-+$).*`

```
for (String in : new String[] {"trt-09tr-", "---rte434rt", "-", "------", 
                               "---6", "--u"})
  System.out.println(in.matches("(?!^-+$).*"));
```

prints

```
true
true
false
false
true
true
```

Comment: thank alot this did what i wanted. n' i'll accept your answer after 3 min coz some popup is appearing when i tried to accept.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik done thanks again... n' how could you write such an complex regex within less then 3 min. hats off to you man.

Comment: To get that skill, one just needs to hang out on StackOverflow for a while :) Once you get the basic principle for this problem, it is easy to adapt.

Answer (score 3):

Try this regular expression:

```
^-*$
```

Each String that matches can be discarded.

```
String r = "^-*$";
System.out.println(!"----".matches(r));    // false
System.out.println(!"--e--".matches(r));   // true
System.out.println(!"-e-e-e-".matches(r)); // true
```

Comment: --a is not matched for example

Comment: it's not accepting "-8" but this should be BTW check the accepted answer.thank you

Comment: @TheVOYOU `-8` does match (`System.out.println(!"-8".matches(r));` prints true).

Comment: +1 Nice negation: `!(all characters are '-') <=> (there is at least one non '-' character)` ;-)

Comment: @Tichodroma truely a smart answer.